# Moving Questions from Atheism

Tags: discussion, questions

[Atheism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism) was closed after 94 days in beta. I'm sure there is a lot of crossover between content.

What is the best way to import *appropriate* question from Atheism.SE? If possible it would be good to attribute content to the original author.

I think even if its only 10 great questions and answers it worth the effort.

Answer (score 8):

I think there is no need for that, and actually it's probably a bad idea to do a direct migration:

- Any good question that is appropriate here can be simply re-asked
- Our standards, in particular the fact that answers must be referenced, would make most answers in Atheism.SE not appropriate on Skeptics.SE. Again - only a problem if we migrate the questions.

Comment: We really let the Atheism.SE questions slide a lot, too, because we realized it was failing miserably.

Comment: I think there's not a single question in that list that I would save, personally.

Comment: No. I think you're spot on that it would be more work to migrate and modify than just re-ask the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have extracted the 200+ questions from the Data Dump and created a HTML file for easy `copy & pasting`:

> http://blog.bristolskeptics.co.uk/Questions.html

At the very least it might inspire some skeptical questions...

**Edit:** Potential question for re-posting

- Are there any solid statistics that show negative side effects of religion or positive side effects of atheism?
- How to deal with the "presuppositional" argument?
- Evolution as a mathematical and physical process: theory of evolution vs theory of gravity?
- Can one rationally take scientific facts on authority?
- Is there a secular method of measuring years?
- Swearing on the bible
- Do you consider Buddhism a religion?
- Is religion a mental illness?
- Do placeboes work on atheists?
- Are atheists, statistically speaking as a group, more or less loyal than the rest of the population?
- What bogus anti-theistic claims have you encountered?
- Are atheists more liberal than the average population?
- How to answer the question of Spinoza, Einstein, Atheism and "God"
- Is science the religion of atheists?
- Is there anything that religions have accomplished, that couldn't be done without the need for supernatural beliefs?
- What research exists correlating Atheism and Suicide?
- Debating a muslim on the validity of their religion 101 - Science in the Qur'an
- How do you deal with other myths, like Santa?
- Have any studies shown correlation between atheism and particular political affiliations?
- Were any pre-modern societies totally devoid of religion?
- Is there a correlation between atheism and skepticism?
- Name of the theory that dinosaur fossils were placed by Satan.
- Can you believe in evolution and believe in God?
- What are the most difficult questions for atheists?
- Is theism a predisposition?
- Why do people say the Constitution of the United States is based on the bible?
- How can refute the assertion that celestials bodies influence people's behaviour?
- When did marriage go from being a business contract to a religious ceremony?
- Has anyone atheist or agnostic ever seen any supernatural occurrences?
- Do Atheists make more efficient or less efficient soldiers?
- Is Lent essentially a good idea?
- Have any studies been done on the relationship between religious upbringings and serial killers?
- What scientific questions are most pressing considering the concerns of the atheist community?
- What is the True date
- Are atheists smarter than believers... or are they reprobates... totally closed off from the grace required to believe and have faith?
- If there is no God, who started evolution?

Some will need tweaking and some are too broad or localised, but many of these are valid here.

Comment: anything in particular there you think is worth pulling across?

Comment: That's a pretty bizarre list.

Comment: Obviously all skewed towards religion and atheism.

Comment: In my opinion, most of them are offtopic here. Not to mention that nearly all of them are trivial and not interesting.

Comment: most of those .. are not good. I could support maybe pulling the *best* 3 or 4, but that's it

Comment: @JeffAtwood if only there were some way we could vote on the best ones...?

Comment: looking at this list is making me vaguely ill.

Comment: The one about whether placebos work on atheists could be interesting. Ideally, it would be rephrased. Do placebos work even when you know they're placebos? The answer is Yes, which is quite interesting. There was a Ben Goldacre video on Pharyngula which explained this.

Comment: Are these questions still around? I'm getting a "no server found" for http://blog.bristolskeptics.co.uk/

Comment: bristolskeptics.co.uk has moved servers and all the old content was taken down.